# Assigning a keyboard shortcut for a specific Eclipse build configuration

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

In our Java project in Eclipse, we have several build configurations, as we have an engine that when run, builds installation jar for a specific projects according to the parameters it gets, so each build configuration run the same build with different parameters to build installation for a specific project.

Currently, I have to go to the Run Configuration drop-down button in the toolbar to start the engine, and I need to select the build configuration from the list in order to run (or debug) the engine with the required parameters.

I have configured Eclipse to run the last run execution if the button is run instead of selecting from the drop-down menu, but I would really like to have separate buttons in the toolbar for each build configuration (or for my favorite configurations), and even better, have a keyboard shortcut to run (or debug) a specific build configuration. Is that possible?

Comment: For plugin development, the simplest way to grab some informations is still the eclipse help pages: http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?nav=/4

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I was able to put together specific steps based on splintor's thread and get this working (I also added a loop at the top that finds any existing launch with the same name and terminates it, effectively making this a "restart" macro):

To assign keyboard shortcuts to specific Eclipse launch configurations, perform the following steps:

- Install https://sourceforge.net/projects/practicalmacro/, which you
  can inside Eclipse via Help->Software Updates:
  http://puremvcnotificationviewer.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/PracticallyMacroGoogleUpdateSite
- Restart Eclipse and open Eclipse Preferences. You will have a new
  section called "Practically Macro Options", expand that section.
- Click on "Editor Macro Definitions"
- Click on "new..."
- In the list of available commands, scroll down to "Editor Macro script (Beanshell)",
  select it and then click "Add->"
- When the script editor pops up, add the following code to the existing code:

  ```java
  import org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugPlugin;
  import org.eclipse.debug.core.ILaunchConfiguration;
  import org.eclipse.debug.core.ILaunch;
  import org.eclipse.debug.ui.DebugUITools;
      try
      {
        // Terminate process if it already exists from a previous launch 
        org.eclipse.debug.core.ILaunch[] allLaunches=DebugPlugin.getDefault().getLaunchManager().getLaunches();
        for (ILaunch l : allLaunches)
        {              
          if (l.getLaunchConfiguration().getName().equals("YOUR CONFIG NAME HERE"))
          {
            console.write("terminating launch: " );
            console.writeln(l.getLaunchConfiguration().getName());
            l.terminate();
            break; 
          }
        }

          org.eclipse.debug.core.ILaunchConfiguration[] allConfigurations=DebugPlugin.getDefault().getLaunchManager().getLaunchConfigurations();
          for (ILaunchConfiguration config : allConfigurations) {
              if (config.getName().equals("YOUR CONFIG NAME HERE"))
              {
                  DebugUITools.launch(config, "debug");
                  break;
              }
          }
      } catch (CoreException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
      finally{}
  ```
- Note line 11 that checks the configuration name, replace with whatever you want
- Also note DebugUITools.launch command on line 15, you can pass either "run" or "debug"
- In the "Macro info" section at the bottom of this dialog, specify a macro name
- IMPORTANT!: If you want to be able to see this macro in the standard Eclipse key binding dialog, you need to assign an id. I started with 1...
- Click OK
- Expand the "General" section and click on "Keys"
- You can now search the possible key bindings for your new macro's name and assign it to any key you want.
- NOTE: After assigning a key I often had to close and restart Eclipse before the key binding was respected.

Comment: Was working great in Indigo, but I'm not able to make it work in Juno! Nothing happens when I press the keys associated with the macro. Any idea?

Comment: Excellent answer, although the row lines you mention do not reflect the script you have added to your answer.

Comment: Thanks Erik. Line 11 reference was correct, but 13 was not. Updated.

Answer (score 9):

I was able to do it using [Practically Macro](https://sourceforge.net/projects/practicalmacro/) - see [this thread](https://sourceforge.net/projects/practicalmacro/forums/forum/878739/topic/3413787/index/page/1).

Comment: Interesting (+1). Could you detail this answer with some specific extracts from the thread you mention?

Comment: I inspected the thread to get this working and provided an answer with the exact steps listed.

Answer (score 6):

One alternative is to use the accelerator keys to navigate the Run menu and select the right run configuration.

On my computer it is:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>*Number*</kbd>

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> gets you to get to Run menu, then <kbd>H</kbd> for Debug History, then one of the numbered alternatives.

To make a run configuration always be visible in the Debug or Run history menus and retain its position one can do the following:

Select the *Run* menu -> *Run Configurations* -> [some config] -> *Common*, then check *Display in favourites menu* box.

(This answer is a copy of one of my [previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549371/eclipse-launch-shortcuts-for-debug-history/11067880#11067880).)

Comment: Easy, fast and clean. Works for me!

Answer (score 5):

You could define a plugin with some [`launchShortcuts`](http://help.eclipse.org/stable/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_debug_ui_launchShortcuts.html) in it.

[This thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/platform-debug-dev/msg00422.html) is a good illustration.

But to actually bind it, you would need to define a command running that configuration, and bind that command to a key (like in this [`plugin.xml` configuration file](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.technology.m2e/msg00101.html))

the shortcut definition of a launch configuration:

```xml
  <shortcut id="org.maven.ide.eclipse.pomFileAction"
            category="org.maven.ide.eclipse"
            class="org.maven.ide.eclipse.actions.ExecutePomAction"
            icon="icons/m2.gif"
            label="%m2.popup.pomFile.label"
            modes="run,debug">
     <contextualLaunch>
       <contextLabel label="%m2.popup.pomFile.label" mode="run"/>
       <contextLabel label="%m2.popup.pomFile.label" mode="debug"/>
       <enablement>
         <with variable="selection">
           <count value="1"/>
           <iterate>
             <and>
               <test property="org.maven.ide.eclipse.launchable"/>
               <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.runtime.IAdaptable"/>
             </and>
           </iterate>
         </with>
       </enablement>
   </contextualLaunch>
 </shortcut>
```

Then the command:

```xml
 <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
    <command id="org.maven.ide.eclipse.pomFileAction.run"
             categoryId="org.eclipse.debug.ui.category.run"
             name="%m2.shortcut.description.run"
             description="%m2.shortcut.description.run"/>
     ...
 </extension>
```

Then the key binding for a keyboard shortcut:

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">
    <key sequence="M3+M2+X M"
         contextId="org.eclipse.ui.globalScope"
         commandId="org.maven.ide.eclipse.pomFileAction.run"
         schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration"/>
 </extension>
```

Comment: Thanks VonC for the quick reply. I'm a plain Java developer, and never defined a plugin. Can you explain how do I do it? Thanks.

Comment: OK, I installed the eclipse SDK and read some plugnis tutorial, and once I have time for it I'll get into writing this plugin. I just don't understand why it has to be so complicated to simply have a command to run a configuration. I guess I really need to add a wish to the eclipse team (or write it myself...)