# How can I bind a specific key to different launch configurations in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, ide, keyboard-shortcuts, automated-tests, pydev

I have several launch configurations for the code I work on.

One configuration (#1) means "run the unit tests for the file in the frontmost editor (i.e. selected resource)".  I would really like to be able to always make this be bound to a key.

Another configuration (#2) means "run the server that I am working on (in the frontmost project) so I can test it interactively".

Yet another (#3) means "run some automated acceptance tests against the server".

I always want to have #1 close at hand, easy to run from a single keystroke.  Plus, I want to be able to run #2, watch it start up in a console, and when it's ready (since it's not *entirely* trivial to automate this) hit the key for #3.

This is possibly similar to the question for [binding a key to a specific build configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437323/assigning-a-keyboard-shortcut-for-a-specific-eclipse-build-configuration), but the answers there look very specific to builds, and as I'm using [PyDev](http://pydev.org/), I don't have a "build" step at all.

Also, given that I'm using PyDev, an answer in the form of a `pyedit_*` script would be appreciated just as much as a "native" answer for eclipse.

Comment: You don't need run configuration for #1 as there is standard one for this `CTRL+F9`. See [Keybindings quick-reference](http://pydev.org/manual_adv_keybindings.html)

Answer (score 5):

Maybe [Eclipse Runner](http://code.google.com/p/eclipserunnerplugin/) plugin could make it easier for someone to handle launch configurations. It doesn't allow to assign key binding to launch configurations currently but I opened a feature request [Key bindings for launch configurations](http://code.google.com/p/eclipserunnerplugin/issues/detail?id=15)

Comment: Sadly, this project doesn't seem to be actively maintained, so shortcuts may not be available in the foreseeable future. It still is a useful plugin though.

Answer (score 1):

Not to a specific launch Configuration , but you can bind a key to run Last run Configuration ,

```
Windows->preferences->General->Keys->Run last launched external Tool
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following (for **#2** and **#3**), after having those run configurations created:

Go to `Run > Run Configuration > Select the run configuration you want > Common > Display in Favorites Menu > Check Run/Debug`. This will make it always appear as the first on the menu.

This will make it appear in the menu in `Run > History` and `Run > Debug History`, then, you can access it through `Alt+R, T, 1` (and `2` and `3`) to run your configurations or `Alt+R, H, 1` (and `2` and `3`) to debug.

And for **#1**, as `Piotr Dobrogost` said, you can just use `Ctrl+F9` in the current editor and choose which test-cases you want to run (if you select a unit-test -- usually with `Ctrl+Shift+Up` or `Ctrl+Shift+Down` -- it'll be pre-selected for you) -- then, if you configured to always relaunch the last launch, as explained in http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_run.html, you can use `Ctrl+F11` to relaunch the last launch.