# eclipse: put keyboard shortcuts on specific launch configurations

Tags: eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I bind a specific key to different launch configurations in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125257/how-can-i-bind-a-specific-key-to-different-launch-configurations-in-eclipse)

I am launching certain programs many times from the little dropdown menu next to the green run-button in eclipse.

Is there a way to bind keys (like F1 - F12) to those run configurations?

I couldnt find something like this in the preferences under "Keys".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Currently there's no way to bind to a specific launch config (without writing the plugin code yourself).  Here's an example of walking the launch configs looking for a named one:

```
public class LaunchRunAwayHandler extends AbstractHandler {
    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
        try {
            final ILaunchManager launchManager = DebugPlugin.getDefault().getLaunchManager();
            ILaunchConfiguration toLaunch = null;
            for (ILaunchConfiguration config :launchManager.getLaunchConfigurations()) {
                System.out.println(config.getName());
                if (config.getName().equals("RunAway")) {
                    toLaunch = config;
                }
            }
            DebugUITools.launch(toLaunch, ILaunchManager.RUN_MODE);
        } catch (CoreException e) {
            throw new ExecutionException("Failed to launch", e);
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

In theory, you would write a command that provides takes a parameter to pick the name, and defines an `org.eclipse.core.commands.IParameterValues` so you could see all of your launch configs in the Keys preference page.

`F11` is *Debug Last Launched* and `CTRL+F11` is *Run Last Launched*.  You might have to set a preference in *Preferences>Run/Debug>Launching* to "Always launch the previously launched application".  But that will just launch the last one, not switch between launches.

Comment: thanks! yep actually i want to launch very specific programs and not just the latest.

Comment: You answer saves me a lot of time. :)

Comment: IMO the "run last launched" is a very stupid key binding. what if i have two external tools, (for push build to integration, and for clean the build). Pressing the "run last launched" is like playing russian roulette... I *think* I ran the clean last time...