# Quick maven instal as a button in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

When I want to run `mvn install` on a project, it requires 3 clicks: rightlick project > run as > mvn install.

Isn't it possible to show a button in eclipse toolbar at the top the performs a `mvn install` on the currently selected project?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10273026/one-button-maven-build-and-test-in-eclipse Let me know if it works for you..

Comment: For me it is a key-stroke: I have put the _install_ command on `Alt-F12`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably configure a Keyboard shortcut for this.

In eclipse go to `Window -> Preference`. From the left pane go to `General-> keys` 
Find out the `Run Maven Install`, Edit a keyboard configuration in the `Binding` field that suits for you.

Hopes this helps.

Comment: What should I enter in the `When` field? I'd like to just select the project in project view and then when hitting the keystroke it should be installed.

Comment: And furthermore: how can I bind a key to a custom maven command. Because, I'd mainly like to skip test during mvn install, but the `run maven install` shortcut would include testing.