# Eclipse execute Maven build with tests

Tags: eclipse, unit-testing, maven, build, integration-testing

In simple words: How to runs in eclipse tests with building process (as simple as possible)?

I want to execute test defined in pom with every maven build. Currently all is build, but none test is run. When I execute maven test it runs test, but during build it only builds.
How can I add this phase to eclipse build process?

I already read [Eclipse Maven Build and Test with One Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10273026/one-button-maven-build-and-test-in-eclipse), and it is close to optimal, still I would like to run tests with build to be more TDD.

Comment: I think TDD can happen without you needing to test with every Eclipse build. Do you have auto-building enabled for your project?

Comment: Yes I got. I could enter running program with command line, still it is not very convinient.

Comment: To be very clear on your requirements - you want the Maven test goal to be executed whenever Eclipse does an incremental build?

Comment: Not necceserly. Anything that will run my tests after build will be just fine. Maybe I could run maven from command line to execute just tests. I see ant file, it should work, still I would like simpler solution.

Comment: I'm a little confused now. How exactly are you building? After what exact action do you want the tests to be executed?

Comment: I got maven builder, still I can add to project builders anything. I can choose order of actions there. I need run tests after compilation phase.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66908/discussion-between-duncan-and-skorpen).

Answer (score 0):

My solution(might not be optimal):

1. require maven runpath
2. Go to Project -> Builders
3. Add new Program
4. In Edit configuration enter (as on picture):

   Location: your/maven/path

   arguments: test -f /yourProjectPomPath/pom.xml

[image: Running AutoBuild Option]

As on picture tab Build Options -> Check(click) During auto builds option select

5. Save changes and check if all works