# Shortcut for running Android applications and JUnit test separately in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, toolbar, eclipse-adt

I'm always running an Android application and a JUnit tests (not Android JUnit Test) back and forth. I've used the Run toolbar button in Eclipse to switch between them, which is quite boring after several times. It is possible to assign a **run configuration** to a shortcut key in Eclipse? (or at least create a toolbar button that does that)

Comment: Reopen rationale: This question is more narrow than choosing an arbitrary configuration. Accordingly, it has a much less elaborate solution.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437323/assigning-a-keyboard-shortcut-for-a-specific-eclipse-build-configuration) could help.

Answer (score 0):

The standard Run shortcut (Ctrl+F11) is context sensitive depending on which window has focus. Take advantage of this by using Run History to run your app from a code window. Then open the JUnit window and use Run History to run the tests. Now, you can press Ctrl+F11 from either place to run the desired project.

You can bind a keyboard shortcut to the JUnit window and use standard window navigation keys to get to a code window. These combined with Ctrl+F11 make for pragmatic key combination.