# Eclipse launch shortcuts for debug history

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

The Run > Debug History menu item in Eclipse (Helios) contains a MRU list of debug history. These items are numbered from 1 to N suggesting that there is probably some keyboard shortcut or keyboard sequence I should be able to enter to relaunch a previous program but I cannot figure out what they might be. Specifically, if I want to relaunch the debug history item number 2, what must I type to use this feature?

I know that there is the Window > Preference > General > Key settings page which lists the "Debug Android Application binding "Alt+Shift_A, D". This seems like exactly what I want but I can't seem to use it or rebind it to some custom key combination that works for me. Please tell me how to most easily relaunch Android apps in the debugger?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One alternative is to use the accelerator keys to navigate the menu.

On my computer it is:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>*Number*</kbd>

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> gets you to get to Run menu, then <kbd>H</kbd> for Debug History, then one of the numbered alternatives.

To make a run configuration always be visible in the Debug or Run history menus one can do the following:

Select the *Run* menu → *Run Configurations* → *[some config]* → *Common*, then check *Display in favourites* box.

Comment: Certainly works, thanks. Now bonus points if someone can show me how to create my own simple shortcuts to simplify the process. For example, I'd love something like "Ctrl+Shift+1" to debug the first entry, "Ctrl+Shift+2" the second, and "Ctrl+Shift+3" the third. It doesn't need to be "Ctrl+Shift". Any combination of the Ctrl, Shift and Alt would be fine.

Comment: I have tried but not found a solution to that. This can make things a little more convenient however: Run -> Run Configurations -> [some config] -> Common, then check Display in favourites box. Makes that configuration always available in the Run -> Run History menu.

Comment: And it seems to assign a unique debug number, which means that I don't need to read the list when launching, I can just hit Alt RH 3 to always debug my configuration number 3 right? That's not exactly a custom hot-key  but you are right that it is definitely an improvement and will probably give me 70% of what I want. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For macOS users, you can make use of the menu search function:
<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>?</kbd>) => type: `d h 1`
and it will match Run > Debug History > 1