# How do I set a default run configuration in Aptana?

Tags: button, configuration, aptana, default

When I click the run button in Aptana, my application is opened in a browser using Aptana's built-in web server.

I have a couple of run configurations set up for running on an internal server (one for chrome one for ff), but I find having to use the run button's drop down menu every time I want to run my application quite tedious. I'd rather just click the green button and have it use one of my internal server configurations.

When I press run now, a new configuration called "Default" is created using the built-in web server. Is there any way to set one of my internal server configurations as the default?

Answer (score 1):

When pressing Run, it executes the last run configuration. It looks like you could bind a key to a specific configuration by using:

[Assigning a keyboard shortcut for a specific Eclipse build configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437323/assigning-a-keyboard-shortcut-for-a-specific-eclipse-build-configuration)

Comment: Can you please verify this behavior? I have found that it is NOT the case. For example, I have 3 run configurations. I launch #2. It moves to the top of the dropdown list, but when I click the Run button (or use the key binding, Ctrl+F11) it launches #1, and I can't find any way to change it to #2 or #3.