# Shorter way for debugging Maven builds with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, debugging

I have a Maven project in eclipse, which I run with a Run configuration. That configuration does `compile` and `exec:exec` with a script (called *runner*) defined in my `pom.xml` dependent on the OS (`.bat` in Windows, `.sh` in Linux). The runners do OS-dependent stuff and then start Java with my application. Which runner to use is specified with profiles like the following:

```
<profile>
    <id>WINused</id>
        <activation>
            <os>
                <family>windows</family>
            </os>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <runnerForLaunch>${basedir}/src/runners/windowsRunner.bat</runnerToUse>
        </properties>
    </profile>
```

So, when I want to run it, I use `Alt+Shift+X, M` and select the Maven config. Later, I just use `Ctrl+F11`.

When I have to *debug* it, I have to do the following:

1. Edit the `pom.xml` to use another runner script that adds `-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8000,suspend=y` to the Java call.
2. Launch the run configuration.
3. Launch a debug configuration that connects to the debugger.

My question is, can I somehow shorten that process? I regularly forget to undo my changes to `pom.xml` and use the runner I currently do not need.
Can't Maven somehow detect if I run it with *Run as* or *Debug as* and adjust variables depending on that?

Answer (score 1):

If the runner config in your POM supports command line arguments:

- Create another profile containing:

  ```
  <profile>
    <id>debug</id>
    <properties>
      <debugArgument>-agentlib: ...</debugArgument>
    </properties>
  </profile>
  ```
- Use the new property in:

  ```
  <runnerForLaunch>${basedir}/src/runners/windowsRunner.bat ${debugArgument}</runnerToUse>
  ```
- Add `debug` to *Profiles:* in your debug configuration.
- Use `%1` or `$1` at the Java call in your scripts.

Or:

- Declare and supply a property value of `<debugArgument>debug</debugArgument>`.
- Evaluate `%1` or `$1` in your scripts and call Java with different arguments accordingly.

Or:

- Add a property `debugArgument` with 1) `debug` or 2) `-agentlib: ...` to *Parameter Name* / *Value* in your debug configuration.
- Use the property in:

  ```
  <runnerForLaunch>${basedir}/src/runners/windowsRunner.bat ${debugArgument}</runnerToUse>
  ```
- 1) Evaluate `%1` or `$1` for `debug` and call Java with different arguments accordingly or 2) use them at the Java call in your scripts.

Comment: So you basically say that I should have a run configuration and a debug configuration? That could shorten the process a bit, but unfortunately Eclipse's `Ctrl+F11` / `F11` do always run the last recently used configuration. It doesn't differentiate that `Ctrl+F11` runs the last recently used *run* configuration and `F11` the last *debug* configuration.

Comment: @Bowi Sadly, that's true. It's because there aren't two different types of run/debug configurations. The according toolbar drop-downs are just Favorites views. `F11` just switches to the Debug view if a breakpoint is reached.

Comment: And there is no way for a xy configuration to determine if it has been started using *run* or *debug*?

Comment: @Bowi Not that I'm aware of. But see [Assigning a keyboard shortcut for a specific Eclipse build configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1437323/1744774) and also [Eclipse - Adding Java 'Application Run' Shortcuts to toolbar](http://superuser.com/q/57352/516482).

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you don't need to add debug options because eclipse simply adds them by calling "mvnDebug" instead of "mvn" when debugging a maven project. I suggest you simply run the shell script before you run your Java app, and start the Java app using exec:java in order to have it run inside the maven process that is attached to the eclipse debugger.