# Eclipse keybindings. Setting up a shortcut for executing a specific run configuration

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, keyboard-shortcuts, run-configuration

I'm trying to setup a key binding in Eclipse to directly execute a background Java file. My file is called CodeChecker.java and it's sufficient for my purposes to run the main method without any arguments. I need to run it repeatedly and so I'm trying to setup a shortcut key to run it directly without having to bring up the Run... menu or having to bring up the file itself.

As far as I'm aware Eclipse is not able to offer this functionality directly. I've tried using a plugin called Practically Macro according to this answer [Assigning a keyboard shortcut for a specific Eclipse build configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437323/assigning-a-keyboard-shortcut-for-a-specific-eclipse-build-configuration). But this answer is horribly out of date and doesn't work any longer.

So I'm wondering if Practically Macro can still be used to achieve this? Any other solution, plugin, script or otherwise would be equally welcome.

Comment: [Eclipse offers this functionality by so-called plug-ins](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/eclipseplatform.html).

Comment: Hi yes you're right thanks, I see there is a tutorial specifically for defining key bindings. I might try this